# How to add tab space in VF page

Tags: visualforce

I want to Add tab spaces in the current Account VF page. 
i.e There needs to be white space between the fields

e.g

```
<apex:form>
<apex:inputText value="{!AccountNumber}"/>
... Add space here ...
<apex:inputText value="{!AccountStage}"/>
```

Comment: Add a screen shot that illustrates what you want to be different. Generally, if you use the `apex:` tags in  conventional way you will get appropriate spacing. If you want a blank space instead of a field you can add `<apex:outputText/>`.

Comment: You can use &nbsp; as many times as you need the space.

Comment: @KeithC- my requirement is to add significant space both horizontally as well vertically between two fields.

Comment: @krishsfdc- Can you please give an example of the code ? I have edited my sample code.

Comment: use `margin css` to set the space.

Comment: <apex:form>
<apex:inputText value="{!AccountNumber}"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<apex:inputText value="{!AccountStage}"/> @SFDCRookie

Comment: @krishsfdc- The reference to entity "n" must end with the ';' delimiter. [This error is being thrown]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<apex:inputText value="{!AccountNumber}" styleClass="ClassName"/>
<style>
.ClassName {
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
```

You can use basic HTML and CSS to achieve this.

Comment: @Shankar - Do I need to add any static resource for that?

Comment: @SFDCRookie its best practice to use static resources. But for you you and add in file css as we do in HTML

Comment: Thanks @Shankar . But in this case , if a field is required , the red bar extends hugely on both sides of the text box . Is there any way to restrict the red bar to the input box?